# Authorizing my Google API app by going through the OAuth2 flow only once

Tags: java, authentication, oauth, google-api, google-api-java-client

I'm working on an application to add tasks to some accounts Using "Google tasks API" for java Using Oauth 2.0.

the problem is every time i want to add a task on an account i have to authentication page and authorize  it using the account and password  , and then wait for callback to add the task and this is not practical

i wonder if there is another way to authorize the java application without executing it and to avoid the callback function :

maybe by sending a link to the owner of the Gmail account, by sending an email, etc..

so all what i want to do is :

1. i want the user of application to authorize it from outside without executing it
2. when i execute it to add the task i just want to cheek out if it authorized from the user i add task , if not i skip it to another user etc..

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical OAuth 2.0 flow goes as follows:

1. Send a request for permission to access the user's data within a certain scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks)
2. User gets the authentication screen where they must log in and allow your app to "Manage your tasks"
3. Your app receives an **authorization code**
4. Your app must exchange the authorization code for an **access token** and a **refresh token**.

The access token can be used to make authenticated requests to the users data, but it will expire after a set amount of time. The refresh token never expires (unless the user revokes your app's privileges in their account settings) and can be used to get a new request token.

You can see the whole flow here in the [OAuth2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

If you follow the flow correctly and save the two tokens (in a database or file, depending on the platform) then the user should have to see that screen *only once*.

Now the best part: **the Google API Java client library should handle this all for you**.  The exact class to use changes depending on which version of the library you use, but you should be setting the place to persist the tokens when creating your service object.  For example, with the calendar API:

```
// For this example we're saving the credentials in a file on the system,
//  rather than a database.
FileCredentialStore credentialStore = new FileCredentialStore(
    new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/calendar.json"), JSON_FACTORY);

// set up authorization code flow
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR))
    .setCredentialStore(credentialStore)  // This will store the tokens for you
    .build();
```

You can check this out in the [calendar-cmdline-sample here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/cmdline/CalendarSample.java?repo=samples#80).  There are [plenty of other samples too](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/), to see the authorization flow on App Engine or Android.

Comment: thank for you answer  :) .. i have a question .. what does "user.home" mean in the code ?

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.home")` references whatever the system identifies as the user's home directory. On Unix machines, that's often represented by `~`. This line is constructing a path to the file where the credentials are saved. So on a unix machine, it may be at `~/.credentials/calendar.json`

Comment: hey nick i was wondering if you could help me with this problem here  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809398/google-tasks-authentication-with-2-legged-oauth-error-401-unauthorized) 

i really have no idea what is wrong about my code source